# cannot add company to contacts in office 365 GAL ...?

Tags: powershell, outlook, ms-office, office365, gal

if you import contacts from the office 365 GAL as contacts in outlook 2013 the company field shows up blank. i cannot for the life of me figure out how to add our company to our contacts. anyone?

i searched through the settings in the office 365 portal and found no way to apply the company name to the contacts. so if you go to people in outlook 2013 and choose a list view, the company column is blank.

**solution:**

```
Get-User -Identity $user | Set-User -Company "The Company Name"
```

Comment: Is this a programming question?

Comment: should have been a powershell question ... i'll edit main post along with solution

Comment: Glad you found your solution. Be sure to post your solution as an answer instead of an edit, and then accept it after the waiting period expires so others know that this question has been resolved.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**solution:**

```
Get-User -Identity $user | Set-User -Company "The Company Name"
```